# Python. finding the largest number and smallest number

Tags: python

when I enter a sequence of numbers like [2, 6, 9, 4, 8 ,7] to find the largest and smallest number it shows that (8, 7) are the largest and smallest numbers what is the error in my code?

```
def minmax():

    x = int(input("Enter the number of integers you want: "))

    mylist = [int(z) for z in input("Enter the numbers separated by a space and then click Enter: ").split()]


    l = mylist[0]

    for i in range(1, x):
        if mylist[i] > mylist[i - 1]:
            l = mylist[i]
        else:
            a = i
            while a < x - 1:
                if mylist[a + 1] > l:
                    l = mylist[a + 1]
                a += 1

    s = mylist[0]

    for i in range(1, x):
        if mylist[i] < mylist[i - 1]:
            s = mylist[i]
        else:
            a = i
            while a < x - 1:
                if mylist[a + 1] < s:
                    s = mylist[a + 1]
                a += 1

    print((l, s), "are the largest and smallest numbers")

minmax()
```

Comment: `if mylist[i] > mylist[i - 1]:` do you mean `if mylist[i] > l`? And then just drop the `else` branch completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u only want to find the largest and the smallest number, you can let out the *else* statements. This works:

```
x = int(input("Enter the number of integers you want: "))

mylist = [int(z) for z in input("Enter the numbers separated by a space and then click Enter: ").split()]


l = mylist[0]

for i in range(1, x):
    if mylist[i] > l:  # I changed mylist[i-1] to l
        l = mylist[i]


s = mylist[0]

for i in range(1, x):
    if mylist[i] < s:  # I changed mylist[i-1] to s
        s = mylist[i]


print((l, s), "are the largest and smallest numbers")

minmax()
```

Comment: Upvote because this answer at least modifies the original code rather than replacing. You should consider adding an explanation as to why the original code fails.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) functions? For example:

```
>>> my_list =  [2, 6, 9, 4, 8 ,7]
>>> min(my_list)
2
>>> max(my_list)
9
```

As far as error in your code is considered. You have to make changes in your `if` condition. Change:

- `if mylist[i] > mylist[i - 1]` --> `if mylist[i] > l:` and
- `if mylist[i] < mylist[i - 1]` --> `if mylist[i] < s:`

and remove the `else` part.

Comment: Whilst this was the obvious answer, it doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't behave as they expect.

Comment: Obviously because it's an exercise in implementing an algorithm, not just getting the answer.